# does GCC -E -MD have a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: c++, gcc

The current GCC manual says

"If -MD is used in conjunction with -E, any -o switch is understood to specify the dependency output file"

That's not what I am seeing:

```
>echo -n > dir/foobar.cpp
>g++ -E -MD -c dir/foobar.cpp -o dir/foobar.o
>cat dir/foobar.o
# 1 "dir/foobar.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "dir/foobar.cpp"
```

`dir/foobar.o` does not have dependency information, but is simply the preprocessed result.

Question 1. Why?

Moreover, if that were so, I would still expect, that `dir/foobar.d` would be the correct dependency information.  It is not:

```
>cat dir/foobar.d
foobar.o: dir/foobar.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h
```

It should be `dir/foobar.o:`...  That is how it is when I don't use `-E` - but with `-E`, the directory prefix is dropped.

Question 2. Why??

Comment: Which version of GCC, on which platform?

Comment: the latest,  gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC)

Comment: Testing with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks, I can't reproduce the problem. Using either `gcc` or `g++`, using `-MD -E` or `-E -MD`, with output names specified as `-o xyz-MD-E`, then the file `xyz-MD-E` contained the preprocessed output file, and the file `xyz-MD-E.d` contained the dependency information. Example, given source file `mppsel.cpp` and the command: `g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -E -MD -o mppsel-E-MD -c mppsel.cpp` — output file `mppsel-E-MD` contained preprocessed source and `mppsel-E-MD.d` contained dependencies. Reversing `-MD -E` made no difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, yes, and that is exactly what is wrong.  Read my message.  What you are seeing is what I am seeing, and not what the manual says.  Moreover, did you test the subdirectory, the way I am doing?  There is a reason why I am using a subdir - because it is wrongly stripped from the dependency file target.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repeat steps that you've made. I used this example to check things out:

```
// test.cpp
#include "boost/bimap.hpp"
#include "boost/container/map.hpp"
#include "boost/container/vector.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::bimap<int,int>          b;
    boost::container::map<int,int> m;
    boost::container::vector<int>  v;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I tried to run following command:

```
g++ -MD -E -o test.d test.cpp
```

The result was a processed output. On the other hand when I run this command:

```
g++ -MD -E test.cpp -o test.e
```

the result was:

- dependencies list as in makefile followed by,
- whole line of NULL chars followed by,
- incomplete preprocessed result.

From my point of view this is clearly a bug: to get clear list of dependencies you'd not only have to run arguments in correct order but also trim the result to remove NULL characters together with everything that follows them.

Important point is what my version is `g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`, while there are already versions like `4.8.2` and `4.9.0` (in development). If those versions also have this bug, you are free to let them know they have a unresolved problem.

**EDIT**

As for your second question I received something like this:

```
test.o: Workspaces/test.cpp /usr/include/boost/bimap.hpp \
 /usr/include/boost/bimap/bimap.hpp /usr/include/boost/config.hpp \
 /usr/include/boost/config/user.hpp \ 
...
```

same as you. I think the problem is, that you only passes those 2 file names as parameters: source's file name and output file name. Output's name only describes where current results go, not how .o file should be named:

```
If `-MD' is used in conjunction with `-E', any `-o' switch is
     understood to specify the dependency output file (but *note
     -MF::), but if used without `-E', each `-o' is understood to
     specify a target object file.
```

from [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/help-gplusplus@gnu.org/msg00656.html).

So you basically either specifying object file (without `-E`) or dependency file (with `-E`) and then g++ assumes some default name for an `.o` file.